# Swift | Initialize new application

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I've started learning Swift while following some tutorials.
After creating a simple view controller, I played the simulator and blank display is appeared.

1. The controller contains only `UITextField`, which references to the `@IBOutlet`
2. I've verified that `main` interface is my `storyboard`
3. I defined the controller class in the storyboard

Still, blank display.. any suggestions?

Comment: Is the ViewController containing the TextField the initial view controller (does the arrow point at it in interface builder)? Is the TextField initialized with any value (otherwise you won't see it)? Does the TextField have any constraints (otherwise it might not be within the screen bounds)?

Answer (score 1):

**Show below image and do like that if you not do it.**
[image]

Comment: It's have been already marked as this. The problem is blank white page - I can see the battery and carrier, but not the other objects.